# Sum DataFrame rows a column contains a substring

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this DataFrame:

```
df1:
      Date Value       Info
        1    1    XXX.othertext2
        1    4    somerandomtext
        1    2    XXX.othertext2
        1    3    XXX.othertext3
        1    2    XXX.othertext3
        1    1    XXX.othertext2
        1    1    XXX.othertext3
        2    6    somerandomtext
        2    9    XXX.othertext2
```

I want to sum rows by same `Date` that start with `XXX.othertext2` until a new `XXX.othertext2` or `sometext` (so it is the sum of fisrt `XXX.othertext2` + all `XXX.othertext3`). The resulting row value of `Info` will be `XXX.othertext2`:

```
newdf:
          Date Value      Info
            1    1    XXX.othertext2
            1    4    somerandomtext
            1    7    XXX.othertext2
            1    2    XXX.othertext2
            2    6    sometext
            2    9    XXX.othertext2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, with a custom `grouper`:

```
grouper = ((b.Info.str.contains('some')) | (b.Info == 'XXX.othertext2')).cumsum()
b.groupby(['Date', grouper]).sum().reset_index()
```

You can refine it more with a regex if necessary.